# How Can we Get The Center position of each cell in UITableView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can we get the center position means Y coordinate of the each cell in `UITableView` in iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using following code but it will give you relative position with respect to cell's `superview`, i.e.

```
tableview
int numberOfSections = [yourTableViewObject numberOfSections];
int numberOfRows = 0;
NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = nil;
UITableViewCell *tempCell = nil;
for(int i=0;i<numberOfSections;i++
{
  numberOfRows = [yourTableViewObject numberOfRowsInSection:i];
  for(int j=0;j<numberOfRows;j++
  {
    tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i];
    tempCell = [yourTableViewObject cellForRowAtIndexPath:tempIndexPath];
    NSLog("Y postion for cell at (Row = %d,Section = %d) is : %f",tempCell.frame.origin.y);
  }  
}
```

In above code we are looping through all the cells we have created and printing its `y` coordinate.